# How do I pass a handle of DXGI shared resource to another process?

Tags: directx, dxgi

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174562(v=vs.85).aspx

According to the documentation of IDXGIResource::GetSharedHandle, I should be able to "marshal this handle to another process to share a resource with a device in another process".

But it's not clear how to pass this handle. Can I just pass the value of this handle to another process? Or do I need some specific method?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can pass this handle directly to another process and access it via OpenSharedResource function.

Comment: Thanks. worked in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can pass this handle directly to another process and access it via OpenSharedResource function.

Answer (score 3):

[Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi/nf-dxgi-idxgiresource-getsharedhandle) now suggests using `CreateSharedHandle()` instead of `GetSharedHandle()` and creating the texture with `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE`.  I had to call `DuplicateHandle`() in order to pass the created `HANDLE` to another process to be opened with `OpenSharedResource1()`.

Comment: CreateSharedHandle() requires IDXGIResource1

Comment: I'm having some difficulties with this. I'm curious why you needed to use `DuplicateHandle()`, when others say they can use the handle directly in the other process?

Comment: @JarrodSmith, CreateSharedHandle returns a "NT" handle which is local to the process, but can be passed to a different process via DuplicateHandle. On the other hand, GetSharedHandle returns a completely different, OS-global handle that can be directly (as a numerical value) used in all processes. To confuse matters, they both use the same C type for the handle.