# How do I pass a handle of DirectX shared resource to another (unrelated) process?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm trying to pass a `HANDLE` between two unrelated processes (no child process).

This `HANDLE rSharedHandle` comes from `DXDevice9->CreateTexture(w, h, 1, 0, D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &pTexture9, &rSharedHandle);`

And I want / need to use it on the other side to be shared using `DXDevice11->OpenSharedResource(rSharedHandle, __uuidof(ID3D11Resource), (void**)(&TmpResource11));`

The complete explanation of the procedure is can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11device-opensharedresource).

I came across this question which as answers but not clear enough that I understand what they mean. [See this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527906/how-do-i-pass-a-handle-of-dxgi-shared-resource-to-another-process/54518441).

I also came across the `marshal_as` which is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/marshal-as?view=vs-2017), but I don't understand how to use it in my case. Further details about the types taken can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/overview-of-marshaling-in-cpp?view=vs-2017).

EDIT (1):
I don't want to deal with managed code if possible. So I search more about "How to pass/share handle between processes". I came across the function `DuplicateHandle()` ([See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle#remarks)) but I cannot find whether it doesn't work because the type of the handle is not a valid type ([See list in Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/handleapi/nf-handleapi-duplicatehandle#remarks)), or whether it is because of something else (unknown).

Moreover,  the second process handle needs to be send before DuplicateHandle() (to be used in the function itself) and the resulting duplicated handle needs to be send to the second process (to finally be used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple (and gross) way to do it. It is more a proof of work than a final product but it is working!

The way I proceed was the following:

1. Create the `rSharedHandle` from the texture in the first process (lets call it P1)
2. I write to a binary file the 8 bytes corresponding to the handle
3. In P2, I read the same file and set the `rSharedHandle` (in P2)

And as easy as it seems, it works well.

Feel free to ask questions in the comment if you want/need more details.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mix managed and unmanaged code? - If no, I assume all the documentation on marshalling might not be necessary. Assuming, you already have some means of transferring data between both processes, I would try the following direct way:

Looking into the Windows headers (e.g. winnt.h), we can find the typedef for HANDLE:

```
typedef void *HANDLE;
```

Thus, you could try to static_cast the handle to an uint64_t (on x64 systems) on the sender side, transfer it to the receiver and static_cast it back to a HANDLE.

Comment: Is the `HANDLE` pointer valid system wide? Because if it is not the case, the pointer should trigger a segfault because the pointer will point outside the process space.

Comment: `static_cast<UINT64>(rSharedHandle);` Doesn't work, "E0171: Invalid type conversion"

Comment: I agree, that if HANDLE was a regular pointer into the application's address space, this could not work. However, I do think (but cannot prove, sorry) that HANDLE is something system wide.

What about `uint64_t d = (uint64t)rSharedHandle`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. There might be some other things that makes it harder than a simple conversion.