# Sharing ID3D11Texture2D between processes yields invalid argument error

Tags: ipc, directx-11, dxgi

I'm attempting to share a ID3D11Texture2D between processes using named shared handle. My tests work fine between threads, but when I do the same between two running applications, I get `E_INVALIDARG` back, as if the texture was not properly created or something else was not allowing it to share (I get the same error on handle creation when texture doesn't have the flags set correctly for example).

Handle creation:

```cpp
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
    _tex->GetDesc( &texDesc );

    // check if can be shared
    if ( !( texDesc.MiscFlags & D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED ) 
         || !( texDesc.MiscFlags & D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED_NTHANDLE ) ) {
         return -1;
    }

    IDXGIResource1 *dxgiResource = nullptr;
    auto result = _tex->QueryInterface( IID_PPV_ARGS( &dxgiResource ) );
    if ( FAILED( result ) ) {
        return -1;
    }
    // convert name to wide string
    auto wHandleName = ToWString( handleName );
    result = dxgiResource->CreateSharedHandle(
            NULL, 
            DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_READ | DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_WRITE, 
            wHandleName.c_str(), 
            &_sharedHandle );
    }

    dxgiResource->Release();

    if ( FAILED( result ) ) {
        return -1;
    }
```

Handle opening:

```cpp
    ID3D11Texture2D *sharedTexture;
    auto result = d3d11Device1->OpenSharedResourceByName( ToWString( handleName ).c_str(),
                                                          DXGI_SHARED_RESOURCE_READ,
                                                          IID_PPV_ARGS( &sharedTexture ) );

    // this is where the error happens
    if ( FAILED( result ) ) {
        return nullptr;
    }
    DEFER( { sharedTexture->Release(); } );
```

I'm storing the texture and handle until they are captured and freed by another process, the tests that spawn threads and use this code between threads are working fine.

Documentation says that it's not necessary to use `DuplicateHandle`, using the name should be enough.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to remove  the `dxgiResource->Release()` call

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42527906/how-do-i-pass-a-handle-of-dxgi-shared-resource-to-another-process ?

Comment: @SimonMourier - this unfortunately didn't change anything. 

@Swift-FridayPie - Thanks. I was hoping to use the named shared handle to avoid the overhead that the `DuplicateHandle` requires, especially as I don't necessarily know the other other process pid. I was under the impression that this was what the purpose of `OpenSharedResourceByName`, but maybe I'm mistaken.

Comment: Do you have a fully reproducing simple project https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was trying to open the resource that was shared on a different adapter (GPU). Sharing on the same adapter works fine.

Comment: @mash Thanks a lot for that. When you want to share a resource between processes, you need to use the same `IDXGIAdapter` to retrieve/create the device. If you use a different adapter, you need to copy the resource to host (cpu) memory and then create it on another adapter. Maybe someone wiser knows of a solution that does not involve this step, but I was unable to find one.

Comment: yep, totally makes sense and it did end up being the issue I was encountering.